# Excel's formula commenting using +N("...")

Tags: excel-formula

`=VLOOKUP(Q3096&" ",'C:\Users\13169\Desktop\December 2020\FL80\[MPR HEADER (DECEMBER 2020).xls]WORKSHEET'!$O$31:$O$51,1,0)+N("Comment")`I am trying to add comment inside Excel's formula using +N("..."). Sometimes, it is working and sometimes it is not (Do not know why?). The vlookup formula is returning #value! error. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Why use `N()` over an adjacent column?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to add the comment if the vlookup is not returning any value try this:

> =IFNA(VLOOKUP(Q3096&" ",'C:\Users\13169\Desktop\December 2020\FL80[MPR HEADER (DECEMBER
> 2020).xls]WORKSHEET'!$O$31:$O$51,1,0),"Comment")

for older versions that don't have "IFNA" formula try this:

> =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Q3096&" ",'C:\Users\13169\Desktop\December 2020\FL80[MPR HEADER (DECEMBER
> 2020).xls]WORKSHEET'!$O$31:$O$51,1,0)),"Comment",VLOOKUP(Q3096&"
> ",'C:\Users\13169\Desktop\December 2020\FL80[MPR HEADER (DECEMBER
> 2020).xls]WORKSHEET'!$O$31:$O$51,1,0))

Comment: Thank you. Can you shed some light on why vlookup with N() is sometimes returning this error? N() combined with SUM() or some other functions appear completely fine.

Comment: N() function is used to show the comment in the formula bar and result appearing in the cell is the result of vlookup function if it is returning an error that will be displayed on the cell but N() will not replace the error

Comment: Interesting. here in this case, the vlookup itself, isolately, works fine. It returns the error when I add +N() to it.

Comment: it seems that vlookup is returning a text value while N("Comment") will return 0 (passing a text to N() always retuen 0) and having the plus sign "+" between vlookup and N() will result into arithmetic addition operation to occur between a text and a number which will result into #VALUE! error

Comment: You are right. I just experimented this and you are right. Then N() is limited to only formulas that return numeric results. Could you suggest some intelligent ways for in-cell commenting like the one you did as ISNA/IFNA? Thanks.